# How scrapy process the Request's callback function result?

Tags: python, callback, scrapy, iterable

Anyone can explain how scrapy call and process the Request's callback function result?

I understand scrapy can accept result of Object (Request, BaseItem, None) or Iterable of the Objects. For example:

**1. Return Object (Request or BaseItem or None)**

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    return scrapy.Request(...)
```

**2. Return Iterable of Objects**

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    for url in self.urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(...)
```

I'm thinking they are processed like this somewhere in scrapy's code.

```
# Assumed process_callback_result is a function that called after 
# a Request's callback function has been executed.
# The "result" parameter is the callback's returned value

def process_callback_result(self, result):

    if isinstance(result, scrapy.Request):
        self.process_request(result)

    elif isinstance(result, scrapy.BaseItem):
        self.process_item(result)

    elif result is None:
        pass

    elif isinstance(result, collections.Iterable):
        for obj in result:
            self.process_callback_result(obj)
    else:
        # show error message
        # ...
```

I found out the corresponding code in `<PYTHON_HOME>/Lib/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py` in `_process_spidermw_output` function:

```
def _process_spidermw_output(self, output, request, response, spider):
    """Process each Request/Item (given in the output parameter) returned
    from the given spider
    """
    if isinstance(output, Request):
        self.crawler.engine.crawl(request=output, spider=spider)
    elif isinstance(output, BaseItem):
        self.slot.itemproc_size += 1
        dfd = self.itemproc.process_item(output, spider)
        dfd.addBoth(self._itemproc_finished, output, response, spider)
        return dfd
    elif output is None:
        pass
    else:
        typename = type(output).__name__
        log.msg(format='Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, '
                       'got %(typename)r in %(request)s',
                level=log.ERROR, spider=spider, request=request, typename=typename)
```

But I can't find the part of `elif isinstance(result, collections.Iterable):` logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats because the `_process_spidermw_output` is just a handler for a single item/object. It is called from the `scrapy.utils.defer.parallel`. This is the function that handles spider output:

```
def handle_spider_output(self, result, request, response, spider):
        if not result:
            return defer_succeed(None)
        it = iter_errback(result, self.handle_spider_error, request, response, spider)
        dfd = parallel(it, self.concurrent_items,
            self._process_spidermw_output, request, response, spider)
        return dfd
```

Source: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L163-L169

As you can see, it calls `parallel` and gives it the handle to `_process_spidermw_output` function as an argument. The arguments name is `callable` and it is called for each element of the `iterable`, which contains the spider results. The `parallel` function is:

```
def parallel(iterable, count, callable, *args, **named):
    """Execute a callable over the objects in the given iterable, in parallel,
    using no more than ``count`` concurrent calls.
    Taken from: http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/24285.html
    """
    coop = task.Cooperator()
    work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
    return defer.DeferredList([coop.coiterate(work) for i in xrange(count)])
```

Source: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/defer.py#L50-L58

Basically, the process goes like this:
when `enqueue_scrape` is called, it adds the `request` and `response` to the `slot.queue` by calling the `slot.add_response_request`. The `queue` is then processed by the `_scrape_next` which calls `self._scrape`. The `_scrape` function defines the `handle_spider_output` to be a callback function which will process the items from the iterator. The iterator is created when the `_scrape2` is called, when at one point it calls the function `call_spider`, which registers the callback to `scrapy.utils.spider.iterate_spider_output`:

```
def iterate_spider_output(result):
    return [result] if isinstance(result, BaseItem) else arg_to_iter(result)
```

At last, the function that actually convert single items, None or iterators to iterators is the `scrapy.utils.misc.arg_to_iter()`:

```
def arg_to_iter(arg):
    """Convert an argument to an iterable. The argument can be a None, single
    value, or an iterable.
    Exception: if arg is a dict, [arg] will be returned
    """
    if arg is None:
        return []
    elif not isinstance(arg, _ITERABLE_SINGLE_VALUES) and hasattr(arg, '__iter__'):
        return arg
    else:
        return [arg]
```

Comment: So that means the returned value (Request, BaseItem) from callback function (e.g. def parse) is always turned into Iterable? Where is the code to convert the Request/BaseItem into Iterable? From `handle_spider_output`, I only managed to trace back to `_scrape` function, but I don't really understand the code inside.